# Can't change default Ruby version in RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

When I do `ruby -v` I get:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

`which ruby` returns:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

`rvm list` returns:

```
rvm rubies
=* ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

When I change the current and default Ruby version to 2.1.0. then `ruby -v` returns:

```
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]
```

And `which ruby` shows:

```
/home/akhil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
```

But in a new terminal `ruby -v` again shows:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

I don't want to change the default Ruby version every time.

cat ~/.bash_profile returns

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Comment: Dont know how to check content of ~/.bash_profile

Comment: You check the content of ~/.bash_profile by looking at it. Use `cat ~/.bash_profile`. Alternatives to `cat` are `less`, `more`, `view`. Read through [the RVM installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) carefully, and follow their debugging steps.

Comment: Thanks for that. cat ~/.bash_profile returns

[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

Comment: Which installation method did you use? Single- or multi-user?

Comment: I dont know that. I am new in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what command you're using to change the ruby version in rvm, you didn't specify. My hunch is you're using `rvm use`, this is only temporary for the shell session. To change it permanently use `rvm default`:

```
rvm --default use ruby-2.1.0
```

This change will persist to new shell sessions.

Comment: I tried it but it does change the ruby version only for current terminal and doesnot set it as defalut. Default system ruby-1.9.3 is present in /usr/bin/ruby folder.And ruby-2.1.0 is present in /home/akhil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby folder. Should I remove /usr/bin/ruby folder? Please help!